# Is there a solution to the error "toPromise is not a function" in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, promise, rxjs

I keep getting this error while testing: Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._productService.getProducts(...).toPromise is not a function.

I know that toPromise is being deprecated in rxjs version 7 but I am running version 6. Is there a way to fix this or another way to write my code without using a toPromise?

I am getting my products based on the three inputs already defined based on a previous click.

Thank you.

```
    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.product = await this._productService
      .getProducts({
        InputOne: this.inputOne,
        InputTwo: this.inputTwo,
        InputThree: this.inputThree
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since RxJS 7.0 `toPromise()` is deprecated and replaced by [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) or [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I am still running version 6 and toPromise() still isn't working. firstValueFrom or lastValueFrom doesn't work in 6 yet

Comment: Well, then check what `getProducts()` returns